# Any Projection is the Sum of two Projections on two Complementary Subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

$T \in L(V)$ is a projection if $T^2=T$. It it true that if $T$ is a projection then there exist complementary subspaces $U$ and $W$ of $V$ such that $T=P_u+P_w$, where $P_u$ and $P_w$ are the orthogonal projections of $V$ onto $U$ and $W$, respectively,   and how to prove it? I think this is true but I am struggling with the construction of such $U$ and $W$.

Comment: @user1551 I corrected the question. Thank you.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Edited. Thank you.

Comment: @amd Title edited. Thank you.

Comment: The proposition is false.  Consider the zero map for a counterexample.  For any complementary subspaces, at least one of them is nontrivial, so the sum of two complementary orthogonal projections must be nonzero, hence the zero map can't be written this way.